# Gradle copy task not copying the files

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, gradle-task

Can someone tell me why my copy task is not working, i have seen some similar questions here but none of them provided a soultion...

```
    def outputJar = "${buildDir}/intermediates/jar"

// Define some tasks which are used in the build process
task copyCompiledClasses(type: Copy, dependsOn: 'assemble') {
    // get directory for current namespace
    println "Copy compiled classes..."
    mkdir Paths.get(outputJar,'classes')
    mkdir Paths.get(outputJar,'bin')
    from fileTree(dir: 'build/intermediates/javac/debug/classes/', exclude : '**/BuildConfig.class')
    into outputJar+'/classes'
}
```

there are classes in the source folders, and my target folders are being created but the actual copying is not taking place!!!! grrrrr!

Answer (score 0):

Think that the source-spec was wrongful.

```
task copyCompiledClasses(type: Copy, dependsOn: assemble) {
    def outputDir = "${buildDir}/intermediates/jar"
    mkdir "${outputDir}/classes"
    mkdir "${outputDir}/bin"
    from fileTree("${buildDir}/intermediates/javac/debug/classes") {
        include '**/*'
        exclude '**/BuildConfig.class'
    }
    into "${outputDir}/classes"
}
```